# Relation Schema : How to solve this

Tags: database, relational-database

I can't solve it.please help
Q In a **relation schema R = (A, B, C, D, E)**, the following functional dependencies are held:

```
A → BC
CD → E 
B → D 
E → A
```

Which of the following is a combination of **two candidate keys for R**? 
Answer Choice:

**a)  A and E**
b)  B and C

c)  B and D
d)  C and D

The Correct Answer is **a)  A and E**

But if E depend on A ( E → A), then why option **a)  A and E** is correct? please help

Comment: What reference are you using, and what does it say about finding CKs? Where are you stuck in following it? Please read [ask] including about homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute the closure of the functional dependencies for each set of attributes on the left-hand side of an FD:

```
A -> A (Trivial)
A -> ABC (since A -> BC)
A -> ABCD (since B -> D)
A -> ABCDE (since CD -> E)
```

So we can see that A determines all attributes in the relation. A is a candidate key. For CD, we get:

```
CD -> CD (trivial)
CD -> CDE (since CD -> E)
CD -> CDEA (since E -> A)
CD -> CDEAB (since A -> BC)
```

So CD is a candidate key. For B, the most we can derive is:

```
B -> B (trivial)
B -> BD (since B -> D)
```

For E:

```
E -> E (trivial)
E -> EA (since E -> A)
E -> EABC (since A -> BC)
E -> EABCD (since B -> D)
```

Again, we can determine all attributes in R so E is a candidate key.

So we've got candidate keys A, E and CD. Now, read the question carefully. Which of the possible answers are a combination of two candidate keys? Option d has two attributes of a single candidate key. Options b and c contain B which isn't a candidate key. The only correct answer is a) A and E, which lists two separate candidate keys.

Comment: Thanks @reaanb  I've 1 question How do i interpret the syntax A -> ABC.is it ABC Depends on A OR ABC Comes From A.please help.

Comment: I read it as A determines A, B and C, or equivalently: A, B and C depend on A.

Comment: Thanks @reaanb 1 more question you write A -> ABC (since A -> BC) . However here 
A -> ABCD (since B -> D) you didn't replace B with D,Instead you add D How?

Comment: If we know A -> ABC and we know B -> D, then we can conclude that A -> ABCD since A -> D is a transitive functional dependency via A -> B -> D. I suggest you review Armstrong's axioms for more information - Union: If X -> Y and X -> Z then X -> YZ.